# HTTP error 405 when trying to create an apload session with MS Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to upload a large attachment with Microsoft Graph Rest API.
I am able to create an upload session and attach a large file > 3 Mo (file attachment) but when i try to create an upload session to attach an item with a size > 3 Mo to a mail, it fails with an error 405. The Reason is because i'm setting the attachment type to "item" instead of "file". When i try to POST to the API endpoint the Following payload (for testing):

```
{"AttachmentItem":{"attachmentType":"item","name":"flower","size":3483322}}
```

The response (with a 405 status) is:

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAttachmentSessionIsSupportedOnlyForFileAttachments","message":"Unsupported Attachment type specified. Only File attachments can be uploaded using an Upload Session.","innerError":{"date":"2020-12-09T16:03:11","request-id":"ded65db1-179f-45bd-89ba-e5527556f359","client-request-id":"f6befc74-8399-227d-3686-bf2a62297a44"}}}
```

Normally the **"item"** attachment type should be supported according to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/attachmentitem?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Any clue on this ?

Thx

Comment: Outside of your application, can you repro the issue with POSTMAN/Graph Explorer as well?

Comment: Yes same issue when i tried with Graph Explorer. I think it is not supported yet by Graph API while the documentation mention the "item" attachment type.

Comment: hmm, glad that you tested and confirmed. I see the same too. Let me see if i can do anything on this.

Comment: Hello, dou you have any feedback about this issue. it is a very annoying issue i need to know if this feature is supported or not. Thx for your feedback !

Comment: Cool. I looked at it. Here's the update. You're using item attachment type - you can use it only to add the file types "contact, event or message" only. Hence, you're seeing this error. I see that above you're trying to add an attachment called "Flower". Let me assume it's JPG/JPEG filetype, then i would use "file" attachment  instead of "item". I tested in Graph explorer/POSTMAN and it works for me. So i would suggest you to try the same and let me know if you can still repro the issue.

Comment: I took the example in the documentation but in my source code i'm trying to attach a big message with a size of ~5MB as an item attachment but the api call fails at the creation of the upload session. I tried to create an item attachment session through postman but same issue...

Comment: If you used simple upload API then it only supports files upto 4MB in size. For bigger ones you need to use the following way (1) Create an upload session (2) upload the bytes to the upload session. Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) for it. Let me know if this method helps.